# Why does this ptr doesn't get assigned to null with first.next?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

This is question 1.2 from [sp119.datastructure.es site](https://sp19.datastructur.es/materials/discussion/disc03sol.pdf).

The IntNode ptr points to first.next. However, in the next line first.next gets assigned to null, meaning that ptr should also be equal to null. But this just skips the while loop below and this code doesn't work at all, why?

```java
public class SLList {
   public class IntNode {
        public int item;
        public IntNode next;
        public IntNode(int item, IntNode next) {
               this.item = item;
               this.next = next;
        }
   }
   public void reverse(){
        if(first == null || first.next == null){
           return;
        }

        IntNode ptr = first.next;
        first.next = null;

        while( ptr != null){
           IntNode temp = ptr.next;
           ptr.next = first;
           first = ptr;
           ptr = temp;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `first.next` is *copied* into `ptr`, there's no permanent link between them.

Comment: so you are saying that in after ptr is instantiated, its value is independent of that of first.nexts'?

Comment: Variables are not instantiated, objects are. Assignment copies a reference (or a primitive value) into a variable, and nothing more. Copying a value from one variable to another does not associate them in any way.

Comment: But both ptr and first.next are of IntNode type, the assignment "ptr = first.next" means that ptr copies the address from first.next so they both point to the same thing. Therefore after first.next gets assigned to null, ptr should also be since they have same address. What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: They do both point to the same _object_. If you modified that object, then you would see the change through both variables. But variables are like little chalkboards--you can copy the contents of one into another, but then changing one doesn't change the other.